# How to check for positive & negative in Matlab using a while loop?

Tags: matlab, while-loop

My teach gave us a problem where it ask to create a new array in which the values are true if they are positive or false if negative. Check one at the time with each variable and should stop once the element is not zero. I don't know how to finish the code and this is what I have so far:

```
clc,clear
 v=[-13.5 2.5 -32.0 45.0 -23.0 4.25 0.0 0.85 10.0 -1.5];
k3=1;
boolGTZ=v;
while k3<=length(v)&& v(k3)>0
k3=k3+1;
end
```

Comment: Code is made of text. Share thus, the code as text, not as an image.

Comment: clc,clear
v=[-13.5 2.5 -32.0 45.0 -23.0 4.25 0.0 0.85 10.0 -1.5];
k3=1;
boolGTZ=v;
while k3<=length(v)&& v(k3)>0
  k3=k3+1;

does that help?

Comment: [edit] your question.

Comment: does that work?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want an output array that will have True if the corresponding element was positive, and False if the element was negative. If the element was 0, then stop.

If you have to use a while loop, the only real difference in your code would be to increment `boolGTZ` every loop:

```
v=[-13.5 2.5 -32.0 45.0 -23.0 4.25 0.0 0.85 10.0 -1.5];
k3=1;
boolGTZ=[];
while k3<=length(v) && v(k3)~=0
    boolGTZ=[boolGTZ; v(k3) > 0];
    k3=k3+1;
end
```

However if you don't explicitly have to use a loop, MATLAB's vector capabilities are much easier:

```
v = [-13.5 2.5 -32.0 45.0 -23.0 4.25 0.0 0.85 10.0 -1.5];
v1 = v(1:find(v == 0, 1)-1); % ignore array beyond first 0
boolGTZ = v1>=0; % boolean array that is True if element of v is positive
```

Comment: thank u! That really cleared things up